# Use package from vendor files in heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, vendor

I just successfully deployed my project to Heroku except that I am still getting a migration error because a package i used has its migration files, views and controllers in the package which is in /vendor. And as we all know, /vendor is ignored. Please how can I use the files and migration?

I have run `heroku run php artisan migrate` and `heroku run composer install` but no improvement.

I am tempted to remove vendor from gitignore but i doubt it will help.

I really appreciate your support in advance

```
   "require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "bitfumes/laravel-multiauth": "^2.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.3",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "nexmo/client": "^2.0"
},
```

And this is the error I am having

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'heroku_xxxxxx.products' doesn't exist (SQL: select `products`.*, `seller_profiles`.`address` from `products` inner join `seller_profiles` on `products`.`user_id` = `seller_profiles`.`user_id` order by `products`.`id` desc, `id` desc)
```

```html
C:.
└───laravel-multiauth
    ├───.github
    ├───config
    ├───src
    │   ├───Console
    │   │   └───Commands
    │   ├───database
    │   │   └───migrations
    │   ├───Exception
    │   ├───factories
    │   ├───Http
    │   │   ├───Controllers
    │   │   ├───Middleware
    │   │   └───Requests
    │   ├───Model
    │   ├───Notifications
    │   ├───Policies
    │   ├───Providers
    │   ├───routes
    │   └───views
    │       ├───admin
    │       │   └───passwords
    │       ├───layouts
    │       ├───products
    │       ├───roles
    │       └───seller
    └───stubs
        ├───config
        ├───Controllers
        │   └───Auth
        ├───Middleware
        ├───Notifications
        ├───routes
        └───views
            ├───auth
            │   └───passwords
            └───layouts
```

Comment: You can use `php artisan vendor:publish` to publish vendor files to your app, making them available for editing etc. https://laravel.com/docs/master/packages

Comment: I have edited the app and built a lot with the package. The problem is that everything is built as a package in /vendor. So github ignores it and Heroku can’t use it. The package is Bitfumes/Laravel-multiauth. You can check it out and see

Comment: You might have not commited and pushed to Heroku your `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file. Heroku should run `composer install` on deployment (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#pushing-to-heroku, the "Installing dependencies..." step) which should install the packages you added. It is also possible the migrations already ran which I why you are not seeing any migrations running. Never commit your vendor folder, it will give you more trouble than it's worth :)

Comment: @AlexBouma both composer.json and composer.lock have been committed and pushed to remote

Comment: @kerbholz any other suggestion? Please?

Comment: There's [documentation](https://bitfumes.github.io/laravel-multiauth/installation.html) available for that package, did you follow that? As @AlexBouma said you need to run `composer install` on heroku to install the package (which will create the `/vendor` folder). Then run `php artisan multiauth:install` to install the package migration, seeds, views etc. (And as the docu states: "_Publishing Configurations_, _Publishing Migrations_ ..." it is likely that any files needed are already present in your `database/migrations` folder and you already pushed those to heroku)

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question and add said error there? "_I am still getting a migration error because a package i used has its migration files_" What error do you get?

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Thank you @kerbholz

Comment: did you maybe add it in the `require-dev` part of your composer.json?
if so, you'll need to move it to the `require` key.
if not please add your composer.json file to the question.

Comment: @FahdYousri I have just updated the question with my better info. Wish I could add the app vendor file structure for you to see my plight

Comment: , @kerbholz updated the query

Comment: @AlexBouma Just updated my query

Comment: the error you added indicates that you've a table named products does not exist. This has nothing to do with the package but maybe one of your models.